# How to transfer a range from one workbook to another

Tags: excel, vba

I am a VBA amateur currently trying to create a Macro with the following purpose:

Create a input box where the user must select a range of cells and then transfer the information on these cells to another existing workbook.

Here's what I have:

```
Sub Emails()

    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Application.InputBox("Select a range", "Selecione os E-mails desejados", Type:=8)
    '-> **InputBox where the user selects a range of cells, currently working perfectly**

    Workbooks.Open "G:\ANCTID01\S1018_END-USER-SERVICES\S2001_GERAL\11 - Home Use Program\Cargas\White Listing Template - Customers - Copy.xlsm"
    '-> **Opening the Workbook where I need the data to be transferred to**

    Range(rng.Address).Copy Destination:=Workbooks("G:\ANCTID01\S1018_END-USER-SERVICES\S2001_GERAL\11 - Home Use Program\Cargas\White Listing Template - Customers - Copy.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1") 
    '-> **Here's where i can't get it to work, I can't make it copy to the Workbook "White Listing Template - Customers - Copy.xlsm**

    MsgBox "Concluído! Enviar planilha para hupbulk@digitalriver.com" 
    '-> **Message of the concluded action to the user**

End Sub
```

Thanks!

Comment: In the copy destination use the file name without full path. Just the file name with extension `Workbooks("White Listing Template - Customers - Copy.xlsm")` and `Range(rng.Address).Copy` should be `rng.Copy`

Comment: Thank you very much, worked like a charm now!